# Jenkins Declarative Pipeline Stucked at Particular Stage

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

Built a Jenkins Declarative Pipeline, and it is always stuck at Stage-2 as shown below in screenshot.
Command I am using at this stage is  -

```
stage('Restore Application') {
    steps {
        echo 'Restoring Application'
        sshCommand remote: kocserver, command: "/Home/admin/restore_script.ksh"
    }
}
```

One point - the called script does not return prompt - It could be one of the reason, If anyone knows How to avoid this ?

[Pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5etQ.png)

[Script_Execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zvKL.png)

Comment: Have the same issue on a stage, and it's interacting with another machine and I can see on the remote machine that the stage is doing what it's meant to do. But it just freezes and runs the clock. Haven't found anything yet that solves it.

Comment: I had the ssame with "sh" step. I fixed it with setting agent {label "master"} insted of agent any